# cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil for any section other than the first

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a `UITableViewController` and its `UITableView` is static with three sections. I am trying to populate my static sections in `viewWillAppear` like so:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] detailTextLabel] setText:@"Stuff"];
    [[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] detailTextLabel] setText:@"Other stuff"];
    ...
}
```

The first line populates row 0 in section 0 fine but the second line (and in fact any cellForRowAtIndexPath call to any section other than the first) returns a nil cell.

I did a few tests to try and narrow down the problem:

```
[self.tableView numberOfSections] // returns 3 - which is correct
[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] // return 4 - which is unique and correct for my second section
```

so, the table view has the correct sections it seems but:

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] // nil
```

I am very confused - does anyone have any idea what might be causing it?

I have nothing special in the code: it's a straight-forward static table created in the storyboard with all three sections set up from the start; the view controller is correctly a subclassing UITableViewController; I can populate section 0 perfectly and all works as I would expect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You do need to scroll to see the second and third sections, yes.

Comment: @jrturton using outlets worked perfectly. Thank you very for much for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cells aren't on screen when the view controller initially appears, they have probably not been set up. You should create outlets to the cells you are interested in instead and modify the values that way.